# Syntax to be used for WorkbookQuery.Delete

Tags: excel, vba, connection, powerquery

Microsoft website introduces this command on their website below. It says parameter True can be used. But there is not syntax example.

Where can I add deleteconnection true parameter in the example below

```
Dim qwry As WorkbookQuery
For Each qwry in Active.Workbook.Queries
qwry.delete
Next
```

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookquery.delete#return-value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbookquery.delete)

Getting compile error

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly, but this old code should work

```
Sub DeleteEm()
Dim wc As WorkbookConnection
Dim wq As WorkbookQuery
On Error Resume Next
For Each wc In ThisWorkbook.Connections
    wc.Delete
Next
For Each wq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    wq.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a compile error most likely because you typed `Active.Workbook` instead of `ActiveWorkbook` (`ThisWorkbook` can also be used).

Now for the *DeleteConnection* parameter, you can simply make the call like any other sub:

```
Dim qwry As WorkbookQuery
For Each qwry in ActiveWorkbook.Queries
qwry.Delete True
Next
```

Note that in cases where several parameters are optional, it can be useful to let VBA know which one(s) you are setting a value for rather than relying on their order in the Sub call. On your example, that would be:

```
Dim qwry As WorkbookQuery
For Each qwry in ActiveWorkbook.Queries
qwry.Delete DeleteConnection:=True
Next
```