# Deleting content from data model using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've made up an Excel file with a VBA code which extracts data from a variable PDF file using Power Pivot.
After the job is done I've put these lines in order to clear everything:

```
Dim pq As Object
For Each pq In ThisWorkbook.Queries
    pq.Delete
Next
```

All the queries are deleted in this way, but the data in the data model is not removed, so the file gets bigger and bigger every time the macro is run.

I know the simplest option is closing the file without saving it, but I would like to introduce some code in order to clear the data model automatically

I tried fetching for information but all I find is about cleaning the pivot tables. I didn't find anything about data in the data model

Comment: You can try to use the optional parameter for deleting the connection (e.g. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75229247/17172829))